# Spectral analysis of signal that is observed for a finite time ("philosophical" question)

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, stationary-processes

**Background:** We want to estimate the [spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) of a certain real signal $x(t)$, where time $t$ runs indefinitely over the real line (let's say that $x(t)$ may be the realization of a continuous [stationary process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process)). For q quick introduction, see this [nice answer on PhysicsSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/730828/226902).

Following Wikipedia, the power $P$ of the signal is defined as:

$$
P= \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty } T^{-1}\int_{t_c-T/2}^{t_c+T/2} |x(t)|^2 dt
= \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty } T^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x_T(t)|^2 dt
$$
where $t_c$ is some central time of the time window and $x_T$ is the continuation of $x$ by taking it to be zero outside the time window (case C in the figure): before taking the limit, $x(t)$ is effectively prolonged to be zero outside the time window of amplitude  $T$. The corresponding [power spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) is
$$
S(\omega) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty }  T^{-1} |\hat{x}_T(\omega)|^2  
$$

and, because of the [Plancherel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem),

$$
P = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  S(\omega) d\omega
$$

**Question:** Now, imagine we only have access to the function $x(t)$ over the time window $[t_0,t_0+T]$, as in the figure below. Therefore, it is **not possible to take the limit** $T\rightarrow \infty$ and we have to be content to calculate some "finite time" estimate of the "true" $P$ or the "true" $S$. What should we do? [There is a list of methods on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation), but I see no clear and simple discussion of the effect of having a finite $T$.

[image]

In particular, we have various possibilities to continue the signal beyond the temporal window of size $T$. To me, the possibility B sounds quite "natural", in fact:

- case A makes the signal periodic but introduces some jumps that are not there in the original signal (we assume $x(t)$ to be continuous).
- case C is what (I imagine) people do in practice, namely we just consider $x_T(t)$. However, the signal is treated as an impulse of width $T$, while in reality, it is a continuous function $x(t)$ that is not necessarily impulsive.

Are different methods to estimate $S$ from $x_T(t)$ related somehow to the "choice" of how to extend $x_T(t)$ over the whole real line?

**More precisely:** Given the finite time window, we have no access to information on the part of the true spectral density $S(\omega)$ for $\omega \lesssim 1/T$: the observation should be longer than $T$ to probe these low frequencies. Therefore, it should be no surprise if A, B and C will disagree on this "infrared" part of the spectrum. I guess that the three estimates of $S(\omega)$ calculated by implementing A, B, C will be similar on some part of the $\omega$ domain. However, I expect the three prescriptions to give rise to different [spectral leakages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage). Is there a way to estimate this? (or references where this estimate is outlined?).

Comment: Are you interested in estimating $P$ and $S$ or just $P$?

Comment: @Snoop: I am more interested in $S$ than $P$, but any hint is welcome! Also, feel free to remove any "direct current" part of the signal.

Comment: This is a very interesting article that contains some hint: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.02986